# Microsoft Access 2016 - Need to combine SQL query using JOIN .... ON Col1 MOST LIKE Col2

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, sql-like, ms-access-2016

I am working in Microsoft Access 2016.  I have a data table [Data] that contains many thousand rows of data. I have a lookup table [Lookup] that contains all of the project IDs that are known. These tables should combine on the project ID, which is a string field. Normally, I would join these tables using:

```
SELECT * FROM [Data] LEFT JOIN [Lookup] ON [Data].[ProjectID] = [Lookup].[ProjectID]
```

The issue is that the [Data] project ID field is a much longer string that the lookup. As an example

Data:

- PROJECT.TS.01.004.005

Lookup:

- PROJECT.TS
- PROJECT.TS.01
- PROJECT.TS.02

I tried using the following:

```
 SELECT * FROM [Data] LEFT JOIN [Lookup] ON [Data].[ProjectID] LIKE [Lookup].[ProjectID] + '*'
```

The only issue is that there are multiple entries in the lookup table that are "LIKE" the data field.  I need to be able to join on the entry that is not only "LIKE" but has the greatest length of all those that are "LIKE".

It really seems like what I need is to call a function that is "MOST LIKE" but that doesn't exist to my knowledge in SQL syntax.

Any advice on how to join these two tables effectively?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider:

```
SELECT * FROM [Data] LEFT JOIN [Lookup] ON [Data].[ProjectID] LIKE [Lookup].[ProjectID] + '*' 
WHERE Len(Lookup.ProjectID) = DMax("Len(ProjectID)", "Lookup", "'" & Data.ProjectID & "' LIKE ProjectID & '*'");
```

Or

```
SELECT * FROM [Data] LEFT JOIN [Lookup] ON [Data].[ProjectID] LIKE [Lookup].[ProjectID] + '*' 
WHERE Len(Lookup.ProjectID) = (
    SELECT Max(Len(Lookup.ProjectID)) FROM Lookup WHERE Data.ProjectID LIKE Lookup.ProjectID & "*");
```

Comment: This works perfectly. I think the domain functions and their syntax were the key to what I needed. Thanks